# Google SAML APP SSO authentication in php application

Tags: php, saml-2.0, google-admin-sdk, google-sso

I have php application build in Laravel and hosted it in a server.

I have also created a (G-suit) google admin account(https://admin.google.com) with my domainname(http://www.example.com) as a admin i have created few users (abc@myhost.com, xyz@myhost.com) from the google admin console.

Now Instead of creating a full authentication system in my application, What i want is that my users can login to my php application with the email address that i have created for them as admin.

> **How can i do this ?**

Answer (score 1):

You could integrate 'simpleSAMLphp' (https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp) into your app. Then your app will act as a SAMLv2 ServiceProvider and will consume SAMLv2 assertions issued by Google SAMLv2 IdP (https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en). There are also other PHP-based SP-implementations available, or you could use SAML SP Apache http server module if you are using Apache http server.

Comment: thankyou for your response. I am very new to the concept of saml therefor had to idea that i had to convert my application to sp. Now after reading your answer i am going to do so using the library that i will find (eg: onelogin, simplesamlphp etc). i will comment here if i have any problem to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You may check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users) about user accounts. It says that to create a user account using one of your domains, use the following `POST` request and include the authorization described in [Authorize requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing.html).

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users
```

You may check on this [example](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/php).

Comment: this is not what i want